# LogLikelihood Parameter Estimation for Linear Gaussian Kalman Filter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, algorithms, kalman-filter, likelihood

I have written some code that can do Kalman filtering (using a number of different Kalman-type filters [Information Filter et al.]) for Linear Gaussian State Space Analysis for an n-dimensional state vector. The filters work great and I am getting some nice output. However, the parameter estimation via loglikelihood estimation is confusing me. I am not a statistician but a physicist, so please be kind.

Let us consider the linear Gaussian State Space model

$$y_t = \mathbf{Z}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \epsilon_{t},$$
$$\alpha_{t + 1} = \mathbf{T}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \mathbf{R}_{t}\eta_{t},$$

where $y_{t}$ is our observation vector, $\alpha_{t}$ our state vector at time step $t$. The quantities in bold are the transformation matrices of the state space model which are set according to the characteristics of the system under consideration. We also have

$$\epsilon_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{H}_{t}),$$
$$\eta_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{Q}_{t}),$$
$$\alpha_{1} \sim NID(a_{1}, \mathbf{P}_{1}).$$

where $t = 1,\ldots, n$. Now, I have derived and implemented the recursion for the Kalman Filter for this generic state space model by guessing the initial parameters and variance matrices $\mathbf{H}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{1}$ I can produce plots like

[image: Kalman Filter]

where the points are the Nile River water levels for Jan over 100 years, the line is the Kalamn Estimated state, and the dashed lines are the 90% confidence levels.

Now, for this 1D data set the matrices $\mathbf{H}_{t}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{t}$ are just scalars $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ and $\sigma_{\eta}$ respectively. So now I want to get the correct parameters for these scalars using the output from the Kalman Filter and the loglikelihood function

$$\log L(Y_{n}) = -\frac{np}{2}\log(2\pi) - \frac{1}{2}\sum^{n}_{t = 1}(log|\mathbf{F}_{t}| + v^{\mathsf{T}}_{t}\mathbf{F}_{t}^{-1}v_{t})$$

Where $v_{t}$ is the state error and $\mathbf{F}_{t}$ is the state error variance. Now, here's where I am confused. From the Kalman filter, I have all the information I need to work out $L$, but this seems to get me no closer to being able to calculate the maximum likelihood of $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ and $\sigma_{\eta}$. **My question is how can I calculate the maximum likelihood of $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ and $\sigma_{\eta}$ using the loglikelihood approach and the equation above?** An algorithmic break down would be like a cold beer to me right now...

Thanks for your time.

---

*Note. For the 1D case $\mathbf{H}_{t} = \sigma^{2}_{\epsilon}$ and $\mathbf{H}_{t} = \sigma^{2}_{\eta}$. This is the univariate local level model.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you run the Kalman filter as you have, with given values of
$\sigma_\epsilon^2$ and $\sigma^2_\eta$, you get a sequence of innovations
$\nu_t$ and their covariances $\boldsymbol{F_t}$, hence you can calculate the value of $\log L(Y_n)$ using the formula you give.

In other words, you can regard the Kalman filter as a way to compute an implicit function of $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ and $\sigma^2_\eta$. The only thing that you need to do then is to package this computation into a function or subroutine and handle that function to an optimization routine --like `optim` in R. That function should accept as inputs  $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ and $\sigma^2_\eta$ and return  $\log L(Y_n)$.

Some packages in R (e.g. `dlm`) do this for you (see for instance function `dlmMLE`).

**Edit:** Link in one of my comments below, which I cannot edit, is now [here](http://derio.danengain.biz/%7Eetptupaf/ficheros/mastermodmat/Ejemplos/N4.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate that I seem to have all of the components required to calculate the loglikelihood explicitly, however all reference I have seem to suggest that I use $\sigma_\epsilon$ and $\sigma_\eta$ as unknowns in the loglikelihood function and maximise this using a Newton-type method? This is what is confusing me; "loglikelihood is maximised numerically with respect to the unknown state vector" - how?

Comment: The computation of the likelihood is not that explicit, in that $\sigma_\epsilon$ and $\sigma_\eta$ do not appear explicitly in the expression of $\log L(Y_n)$. Rather, they influence the likelihood via $\nu_t$ and $\boldsymbol{F_t}$. Thus, you need to run the Kalman filter to compute $\log L(Y_n)$ for each pair of values of $\sigma_\epsilon$ and $\sigma_\eta$. Once you code that in the form of a function, you handle that to a Newton-type (or any general-purpose) maximizing function and that's it.

Comment: I happen to have detailed code (in R) showing how to do this precisely for the Nile data. I use it as an illustration for my students. Unfortunately it is in Spanish, but I hope the code is pretty clear (and I can translate the comments if not). You can grab this example from http://www.et.bs.ehu.es/~etptupaf/N4.html.

Comment: This is massively helpful. Thanks very much for your time. Your comment has helped a lot! Sometimes it is difficult to "see the wood for the trees" and having something simple explained explicitly is all that is required... Thanks again.

Comment: I would also like to ask whether I could have a look at the page where you go through the state smoothing recursion. Your smoothing looks better than mine and I am not sure why!? I have attempted to find it from your web-site but I can't find the required page...

Comment: Glad if that helped to clarify. I did not program the smoother, rather I used library functions available in R

Comment: So it was not the 'state smoothing algorithm' from Koopman et al.. That might explain things... Thanks again.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. The library functions I used implement the standard smoother which Durbin-Koopman present in their book (and the results agree between them). The difference with your computations must be due to some other reason, perhaps different parameters.